# API documentation in Vert.x

Tags: swagger, openapi, vert.x, openapi-generator

Is there any way to generate apis documentation in vert.x like swagger documentation in spring?

I did my research but didn't find any solution

Comment: Someone in the community had created this https://github.com/phiz71/vertx-swagger
But it is no longer maintained. Vert.x has taken the opposite approach in fact: take a spec and generate a router config: https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-web-openapi/java/

Answer (score 0):

You can easily bring in a dependency like smallrye-open-api create an interface for your services, place annotations and have it generated at compile time. I've done it for many vert.x components that I wrote.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.smallrye</groupId>
  <artifactId>smallrye-open-api-core</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.smallrye</groupId>
  <artifactId>smallrye-open-api-jaxrs</artifactId>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>


<build>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>io.smallrye</groupId>
    <artifactId>smallrye-open-api-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>generate-schema</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
      <infoTitle>Notifier API</infoTitle>
      <outputDirectory>../application/src/main/resources/</outputDirectory>
      <includeDependenciesScopes>compile,provided,system,test,import</includeDependenciesScopes>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

- if the implementation is not in the same module remember to add a mock impl so that the plugin detect the interface as being used.

Comment: I have created manually with swagger.io